# How to measure the performance of the Erlang Garbage Collector?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, erlang

I have started programming in Erlang recently and there are a few things I want to understand regarding garbage collection (GC). As far as I understand, there is a generational GC for the private heap of each process and a reference counting GC for the global shared heap.

What I would like to know is if there is anyway to get:

1. How many number of collection cycles?
2. How many bytes are allocated and deallocated, on a global level or process level?
3. What are the private heaps, and shared heap sizes? And can we define this as a GC parameter?
4. How long does it take to collect garbage? The % of time needed?
5. Is there a way to run a program without GC?

Is there a way to get this kind of information, either with code or using some commands when I run an Erlang program?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend reading [this blog post](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/11/7/logplex-down-the-rabbit-hole) and having a look at the [recon library](https://github.com/ferd/recon), both courtesy of Fred Hébert, also the author of [*learn you some Erlang for great good!*](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content).

Comment: It would be interesting to understand why you ask the question. For example, do you currently have a GC problem with your Erlang application, or do you have disappointing experience from other languages like Java. Remember that the Erlang GC is per Erlang process, whereas GC is per JVM for Java. That means the behavior is completely different. Erlang never makes one big GC.

Comment: "Remember that the Erlang GC is per Erlang process, whereas GC is per JVM for Java" -- I'm well aware of that, thank you!
I'm just trying to understand how good the GC protocol of Erlang. To do that I want to try some benchmarking using this kind of information. BTW if you know any relevant and interesting benchmarks on Erlang, please let me know.

Comment: Good franco. It will be interesting to see when more and more people get aware that GC per JVM is a real problem. Even with "modern" GC like generational, you typically will have a complete stop once per day or so, where the GC blocks the system for 10 to 100 seconds. THe fact that GC isn't a linear process with respect to heap-size has not yet affected system design

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. To get information for a single process, you can call `erlang:process_info(Pid)`. This will yield (as of Erlang 18.0) the following fields:

   ```erlang
   > erlang:process_info(self()).
   [{current_function,{erl_eval,do_apply,6}},
    {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}},
    {status,running},
    {message_queue_len,0},
    {messages,[]},
    {links,[<0.27.0>]},
    {dictionary,[]},
    {trap_exit,false},
    {error_handler,error_handler},
    {priority,normal},
    {group_leader,<0.26.0>},
    {total_heap_size,4184},
    {heap_size,2586},
    {stack_size,24},
    {reductions,3707},
    {garbage_collection,[{min_bin_vheap_size,46422},
                         {min_heap_size,233},
                         {fullsweep_after,65535},
                         {minor_gcs,7}]},
    {suspending,[]}]
   ```

   The number of collection cycles for the process is available in the field `minor_gcs` under the section `garbage_collection`.
2. **Per Process**

   The current heap size for the process is available in the field `heap_size` from the results above (in words, 4 bytes on a 32-bit VM and 8 bytes on a 64-bit VM). The total memory consumption of the process can be obtained by calling `erlang:process_info(Pid, memory)` which returns for example `{memory,34312}` for the above process. This includes call stack, heap and internal structures.

   Deallocations (and allocations) can be traced using [`erlang:trace/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace-3). If the trace flag is `garbage_collection` you will received messages on the form `{trace, Pid, gc_start, Info}` and `{trace, Pid, gc_end, Info}`. The `Info` field of the `gc_start` message contains such things as `heap_size` and `old_heap_size`.

   **Per System**

   Top level statistics of the system can be obtained by [`erlang:memory/0`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#memory-0):

   ```erlang
   > erlang:memory().
   [{total,15023008},
    {processes,4215272},
    {processes_used,4215048},
    {system,10807736},
    {atom,202481},
    {atom_used,187597},
    {binary,325816},
    {code,4575293},
    {ets,234816}]
   ```

   Garbage collection statistics can be obtained via [`erlang:statistics(garbage_collection)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#statistics-1) which yields:

   ```erlang
   > statistics(garbage_collection).
   {85,23961,0}
   ```

   Where (as of Erlang 18.0) the first field is the total number of garbage collections performed by the VM and the second field is the total number of words reclaimed.
3. The heap sizes for a process are available under the fields `total_heap_size` (all heap fragments and stack) and `heap_size` (the size of the youngest heap generation) from the process info above.

   They can be controlled via [spawn options](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_opt-4), specifically `min_heap_size` which sets the initial heap size for a process.

   To set it for all process, `erlang:system_flag(min_heap_size, MinHeapSize)` can be called.

   You can also control global VM memory allocation via the `+M...` options to the Erlang VM. The flags are described [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erts_alloc.html#id190624). However, this requires extensive knowledge about the internals of the Erlang VM and its allocators and using them should not be taken lightly.
4. This can be obtained via the tracing described in answer 2. If you use the option `timestamp` when tracing, you will receive a timestamp with each trace message that can be used to calculate the total GC time.
5. Short answer: no.

   Long answer: Maybe. You can control the initial heap size (via `min_heap_size`) which will affect when garbage collection will occur the first time. You can also control when a full sweep will be performed with the `fullsweep_after` option.

More information can be found in the [Academic and Historical Questions](http://www.erlang.org/faq/academic.html#idp33134160) and [Processes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html#id68993) section of the Efficiency Guide.

The most practical way of introspecting Erlang memory usage at runtime is via the [Recon library](https://github.com/ferd/recon), as [Steve Vinoski mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669870/gc-performance-in-erlang/32678376#comment53188470_32669870).