# Measuring memory performance in Erlang

Tags: memory, erlang, profile

Is there a way to measure the complete memory usage when running a program in Erlang? My benchmarks are such that I spawn a process which in turn will spawn more processes, etc. Towards the end, they are all collapsed until only the initial process receives some result.

I am interested in the highest momentary memory usage altogether. Assuming before I spawn my process that memory usage is 0, what is the peak momentary memory usage?

I looked at this thread: [GC performance in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669870/gc-performance-in-erlang), which describes `process_info/2`. It seems, however, that if I spawn a process the memory reported by `process_info(self(), memory)` does not increase.

[Percept](http://www2.erlang.se/documentation/doc-5.7/lib/percept-0.8/doc/html/percept_ug.html) seems to mainly gather statistics of processes and their lifetimes, rather than their resource consumption.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about the memory BEAM consumes or just your program?

Comment: @ipinak While both measurements are of interest, I believe I'd be more interested in just my program. I do believe my report would benefit from having both measurements though.

Comment: I assume that `self()` is not the process running your code. Have you tried `process_info/1` on another process ID?

Comment: You also can measure the memory footprint as seen by the OS (Windows? Linux? MacOS?). Would this answer your question? Is so, please add a tag with the relevant OS.

Comment: In this case, my OS would be Ubuntu, @user803422 However, primarily I'd be interested in just how my program performs, without accounting for the memory used by BEAM.

Comment: You can measure BEAM alone (eg : a hello world), then BEAM with your application, and make the difference.

Comment: Have you tried observer?